# What to do if one tag is always a subset of another tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, etiquette

There is a tag [hat-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hat-problem) and another tag [logic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-puzzle). Probably every question tagged as a hat problem is one that is solved using logical reasoning, and can be tagged as a logical puzzle also.

Is the common practice just to use both tags?

(Another example: here on meta, [tags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) and [tagging](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging) are similar to each other)

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of [Should \[hat-problem\] be its own tag, instead of a synonym?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3090/should-hat-problem-be-its-own-tag-instead-of-a-synonym) since this issue was re-raised and resolved there, and nowadays it's perfectly fine and common to have *sub-tags*.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I agree, don't have vote to close privilege though

Comment: You do have the vote-to-close privilege (it's 3k rep). More importantly, as the OP of this question you have the right to insta-close it as duplicate by simply accepting it as such on the banner that you should now see at the top of your question.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Got it , option wasn't there on app

Answer (score 0):

I've gone ahead and made [hat-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hat-problem) a synonym of [logic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-puzzle) (as well as [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) => [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) on meta).