# Several tags are special instances of another tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

[This meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/what-to-do-if-one-tag-is-always-a-subset-of-another-tag) from a couple of months ago asks what to do when one tag is a subset of another. The specific example there was [hat-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hat-puzzle) as a subset of [logic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-puzzle). The result was that [hat-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hat-puzzle) was made a synonym of [logic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-puzzle), and the meta question was tagged [status-completed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed).

It is still not clear to me if there is a general policy for dealing with situations like this. Specifically, I am wondering about [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math). There are several tags (perhaps [combinatorics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics), [calculation-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle),[probability](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability),...) that seem to be a subset of [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math). I don't necessarily think it is a good idea to make the other tags synonyms of [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), because the other tags carry more specific information. On the other hand, when someone searches for [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) puzzles, it might be nice if the other tags popped up as well.

Is it possible to have one tag marked as a subset of a second, so that a search for the second also finds posts tagged with the first?

Comment: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/the-math-tag-is-pointless I tried once, failed. Fact is that people may not only be interested in combinatorics puzzles, they might want to search all puzzles that share a mathematical approach of any kind. That's the point of math tag, I think.

Comment: +1, great idea! Another example is that number-sequence, letter-sequence, and word-sequence are all within pattern. Both the subtags and the supertags are *useful*, but it would be nice to be able to see the connection without having to go into the tag wikis. That said, this is probably too big a change for the devs to consider in the near future.

Comment: One way to manage this might be to have a list of similar tags popping up when you type in a tag, in the same way as the list of similar questions does when you type in a title.

Comment: I am personally way more interested in [tag:combinatorics] and [tag:probability] than any other [tag:math] problem, and as I do, I guess other would, so putting all them together doesn't seem like the best idea. Having *supertags* sounds amazing to get the best of both.