# Should [hat-problem] be its own tag, instead of a synonym?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[Julian Rosen's recent post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/several-tags-are-special-instances-of-another-tag) reminded me about something which has been bothering me.

In response to [this post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/what-to-do-if-one-tag-is-always-a-subset-of-another-tag), the [hat-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hat-problem) tag was made a synonym of [logic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-puzzle).  I think that this decision should be reversed: hat-problems are their own interesting category of logic puzzles, which should have a tag wiki introducing the common themes. People might want to search for these types of puzzles in particular, and not having an independent [hat-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hat-problem) tag makes this difficult.

The reasoning for the synonymization was that every hat problem is solved with logical reasoning. There are many categories of tags where a similar argument can be made, like [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars),[weighing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weighing),[sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku),[game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game),[tiling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling), etc, and none of these are synonyms of [logic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-puzzle). Even though every hat-problem is a logic-puzzle, not every logic-puzzle is a hat-problem, so these should not be synonyms.

[There](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/282/hats-and-aliens) [are](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/of-men-and-hats) [several](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9536/1000-logicians-wearing-hats)
[hat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70/n-logicians-wearing-hats-of-n-colors)
[problems](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15764/n-people-n-hat-colors-and-a-one-way-glass)
[on](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/7819/infinitely-many-dwarves-wearing-hats-of-2-colours)
[this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11744/alternating-hat-colors)
[site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11364/five-haberdashers) (each word is a different link), and there will likely be more in the future, so I think they deserve their own tag. What do you all think?

Comment: The hat has now been separated from the head!

Comment: I take a bit of issue with the name of the tag - it should probably be "coloured hats".

Answer (score 7):

I agree that this puzzle type warrants it own tag. I could easily imagine wanting to search for this kind of puzzle of particular.

I think that the tag should be limited to puzzle to devise a strategy for the players to guess their hat colors, and not include puzzles like [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/201/4551) or [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4880/4551), where you are asked to make a logical inference from player's statements. Maybe we need another tag for inductive-knowledge logic puzzles such as [blue-eyes variants](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blue-eyes) or [sum and product](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2780/4551).

Comment: I fully agree with not including inductive-knowledge type puzzles. Perhaps hat-guessing or hat-game is a better tag name than hat-problems.

Answer (score -1):

I would tag it with [hats](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hats) or [coloured-hats](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloured-hats) rather than [hat-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hat-puzzle) or [hat-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hat-problem), as the puzzle suffix tags are supposed to be used for very broad categories of puzzles.

But other than that I definitely agree that hat problems skills have their own tag.